TabControl Tabs Not Visible in Form but Tab contents is visible - using C#.NET
I am adding this tabcontrol to the main form. It seems to work because all code after this is working and subsequent controls are being added fine.
System.Windows.Forms.TabControl Control_TabControl = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
Control_TabControl.Name = "tabControl";
Control_TabControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
Control_TabControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1630, 415);
Control_TabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Control_TabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.Normal;
this.Controls.Add(Control_TabControl);
for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
{
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage
    {
        Name = "Tab" + i,
        Text = "Tab" + i
    };
    Control_TabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
}

But there is a problem, on the form I cannot see the actual tabs. I can see what appears to be the first tab contents, but not the actual expected "Tab1" or "Tab2" control to click.
Inspecting the code during runtime shows that there is indeed 2 tabs as expected and all looks just fine, but its not...
The main form does not have any other controls added in design mode except for a menu bar and status bar.
What could cause this behavior?

I took  your code, created a new WinForms app, and added your code after InitializeComponent but changed Count to 4. I ran it and the tabs were visible. Setting size and location are moot though if using Dock.Fill. You likely have your "subsequent code" doing something that masks the tabs. I'd recommend commenting all the follow-on code out and uncommenting each bit slowly until you find the culprit.

There is no subsequent code that is affecting it. I do believe the problem lies in the provided code, even though it is correctly coded.

In that case, I'd inspect what Count value is for the loop. If I set it to 0 I see no tabs, which is what you report (seeing no tabs). Did you set Count appropriately beforehand?

Count has the expected value of 2 and inspecting the tabcontrol during runtime shows the tabcount is indeed 2.

If I hard-code it as 2 I see two tabs. So given it's only Count that I cannot see how it is set in your code, or where your snippet is relative to other code, I cannot help further. As it works with 2 for me, I'd hazard a guess the issue is elsewhere. Did you add the control using the drag-and-drop UI editor or hand-code? If editor, you might have something like DrawMode set to OwnerDrawFixed.

Sounds z-order problem. What happens if you call Control_TabControl.BringToFront(); after the loop?

When I removed this command:
Control_TabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

it was properly showing up.
It turns out the Fill command was filling the control into the whole main form UNDERNEATH the menu too.
So, in my case, for the code it is used in, simply not using Fill and specifying the size properly was good enough.
